# How to solve framer-motion importing as client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I need help guys. Anytime I import motion it tells me:

> You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

How do I solve this? I tried `useState` and `useEffect`. It only got me more confused. I'm new to React by the way.

Comment: You imported --> `import React, {useEffect} from "react";`  Correct?